# MySQL - Rows to Columns and keeps NULL

Tags: mysql, null, pivot-table

We have the following table (TEST2) in the MySQL database (MySQL 5.6):

```
 TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,TYPE,SCORE
 1,2,A,150
 1,3,B,200
 1,1,B,50
 1,1,A,100
 1,2,B,NULL
```

We try to transform/pivot the above table based on the TYPE column:

If the TYPE column has value == A, move the value in the SCORE column into a new column called A_SCORE.  If the value in the SCORE column is NULL, it should show NULL in the new A_SCORE column.

If the TYPE column has value == B, move the value in the SCORE column into a new column called B_SCORE. If the value in the SCORE column is NULL, it should show NULL in the new B_SCORE column.

The following table is the one we are looking for (the wanted table):

```
 TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE,A_SCORE_MINUS_B_SCORE
 1,1,100,50,50
 1,2,150,NULL,NULL
 1,3,0,200,-200
```

We tried the following query

```
 SELECT TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE,SUM(A_SCORE-B_SCORE) AS ACTUAL_MINUS_B_SCORE FROM
  (SELECT TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,

 CASE
 WHEN SCORE IS NULL
 THEN NULL
 ELSE SUM(if(TYPE = 'A', SCORE,0) )
 END A_SCORE,

 CASE
 WHEN SCORE IS NULL
 THEN NULL
 ELSE SUM(if(TYPE = 'B', SCORE,0) )
 END B_SCORE
 FROM TEST2
 GROUP BY TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,SCORE) AS A
 GROUP BY TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE);
```

It returns something we don’t want:

```
 TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE,A_SCORE_MINUS_B_SCORE
 1,1,0,50,-50
 1,1,100,0,100
 1,2,0,0,0
 1,2,150,0,150
 1,3,0,200,-200
```

If we tried the following, it generates a table close to what we want, but it doesn’t return any NULL value.

```
 SELECT TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE,SUM(A_SCORE-B_SCORE) AS A_SCORE _MINUS_B_SCORE FROM
  (SELECT TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,

 SUM(if(TYPE = 'A', SCORE,0) ) AS A_SCORE,

 SUM(if(TYPE = 'B', SCORE,0) )AS B_SCORE
 FROM TEST2
 GROUP BY TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID) AS A
 GROUP BY TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE;
```

The result of the above query:

```
 TEAM_ID,MEMBER_ID,A_SCORE,B_SCORE,A_SCORE_MINUS_B_SCORE
 1,1,100,50,50
 1,2,150,0,0
 1,3,0,200,-200
```

Could any guru enlighten how to generate the wanted table in this case using MySQL?  The SQL fiddle is here for your convenience.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe7a1/1

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an Sqlfiddle?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe7a1/1

Comment: Here you go. As above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT TEAM_ID, MEMBER_ID, A_SCORE, B_SCORE, A_SCORE - B_SCORE AS A_SCORE_MINUS_B_SCORE
FROM (
    SELECT
        TEAM_ID, MEMBER_ID,
        CASE
            WHEN A_SCORE IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM TEST2 
                WHERE TEAM_ID = T1.TEAM_ID 
                AND MEMBER_ID = T1.MEMBER_ID
                AND TYPE = 'A'
            ) THEN 0 ELSE A_SCORE END AS A_SCORE,
        CASE
            WHEN B_SCORE IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM TEST2 
                WHERE TEAM_ID = T1.TEAM_ID 
                AND MEMBER_ID = T1.MEMBER_ID
                AND TYPE = 'A'
            ) THEN 0 ELSE B_SCORE END AS B_SCORE
    FROM (
        SELECT
           TEAM_ID, MEMBER_ID,
           MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN SCORE END) AS A_SCORE,
           MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN SCORE END) AS B_SCORE
        FROM TEST2
        GROUP BY TEAM_ID, MEMBER_ID
    ) T1
)T
```

[SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3087ca/19)

Comment: At first glance, this looks like an awful lot of query

Comment: @Strawberry You're right, seems to be awful, and I can't even find another way to achieve that. Could you please give me some hints please?

Comment: Thanks!  Your query enlighten me! The core I learn here is "MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN SCORE END) AS A_SCORE,"!

Comment: @Chubaka Yes, that is the core. Pleasure can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the calculation criteria, but something like this should work...

```
SELECT team_id
     , member_id
     , COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN score END),0) a_score
     , COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN score END),0) b_score
     , COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN score END),0) 
     - COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN score END),0) diff
  FROM test2
 GROUP
    BY team_id
     , member_id;
```